# How can I render placeholders inside text in unity to allow drag n drop on them

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-ui

I want to render placeholder inside text to allow drag and drop behavior on those placeholders like this image

[image]

What I want here is how to render this placeholder inside the text object, or even how to place them if the text length is not determined yet

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unity Drag and Drop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49461955/unity-drag-and-drop)

Comment: No, I'm not referring to create drag and drop behavior in unity, what I'm asking for is how to render placeholders within text objects in unity, then I can apply drag and drop behavior to them

Comment: I would split up your text. [Static Text] [Object to render], [Static Text] [Object to render]

Comment: Yes, I thought of this, but this is not a generic solution, also the different screen resolution, font sizes, and other UI aspects will make this solution even unreliable.

Comment: If your objects that you're rendering on drag and drop take similar properties to your text, then you can scale them however (and at the same rate) you like. Prefabs will help immensely.

Comment: Yes, but before the dragged text goes to the placeholder, how can I render the placeholder itself?